# On window x64 build of example crashing at pthread_cancel and pthread_join

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthreads-win32

I have create small program which is working with `pthreadVC.lib` which is `Win32` version. I am using visual studio 2013.

When I have changed program setting for `x64` od same program and then I have linked pthreadVC2.lib (which for x64 configuration) and then my program crashing at `pthread_join` also instead of join I used `pthread_cancel` but having same issue . Also I have build pthread myself  for x64 and linked that library but still having same problem.

My Test Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = NULL; 
pthread_cond_t cond = NULL;

void test(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("\n Threads Working");

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void main() {

    pthread_t threadid;

    pthread_create(&threadid,NULL,(void*)test,NULL);

    pthread_join(threadid,NULL);

    printf("\n FINISH ");
    if (getchar())
        return;
}
```

Error which get on x64 configuration is

> Unhandled exception at 0x0000000180002C70 (pthread_dll.dll) in
>   Pthread64_bit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000000000000001A.

**Edit :**
Also I have copied  example from [pthreads in C – a minimal working example](http://timmurphy.org/2010/05/04/pthreads-in-c-a-minimal-working-example/)
and try to run but having same error in `pthread_join` .

So can you tell me is there any other setting need to do for `x64` or where I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutexes must be initialized, before they are being used. You initialize them to NULL, and then try to use them. This is wrong.

The error message is a clear indicator that a NULL pointer is being dereferenced at a small offset, a member of a struct is being accessed: *Access violation reading location 0x000000000000001A*.

Therefore remove the incorrect initialization, and initialize the mutex before use:

```
const int error = pthread_mutex_init( &mutex );
if( error ) 
{
    //handle error
}
```

and delete it when it is no longer being used:

```
const int error = pthread_mutex_destroy( &mutex );
if( error ) 
{
    //handle error
}
```

Alternatively mutexes can be initialized with: PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER:

```
pthread_mutex mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER ;
```

They should still be deleted using pthread_mutex_destroy().

The other problem is the function passed to pthread_create(). It's type must be `void*(*)(void*)`. The type of your function is `void(*)()`. Even though you used a cast, this isn't correct and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: yes you are correct up voted, but still I have same problem in pthread_join

Comment: i have changed my function prototype to `void* test(void*pt)` and pthread call to `pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, &test, NULL);` still have problem

Comment: Actually it's solved my half problem and half by downloading recent API from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/files  so i have accepted it and suggested edit to you.